# Java binary search tree - insert implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

I have this problem with the implementation of the binary search tree insertion. Now I have tried it with both the recursive method, and the iterative as well. The way that I got so far is "okay at best" since for a tree size = 31609 and tree height = 35 the insertion takes about **100 seconds**, and it is supposed to be WAAAAAAY lower around one second. Can somebody please give me a hint what I might be doing wrong?

Here is the code of what I have managed to do so far (Insertion without duplicates):

```
void insert(int val){
    if(this.elem < val){
        if(this.right != null){
            this.right.insert(val);
        }
        else{
            nodes++;
            this.right = new Node(val);
        }
    }
    else if(this.elem > val){
        if(this.left != null){
            this.left.insert(val);
        }
        else{
            nodes++;
            this.left = new Node(val);

        }
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt the problem is located in the `insertion` itself. Can you provide information about the constructor?

Comment: the constructor is really basic: private Node (int elem){ this.elem=elem;}

Comment: and what does `nodes++` means? Are you storing the size of a tree at every node?

Comment: @CommuSoft it's just incrementing a global variable that I need to keep track of the number of nodes..

Comment: Does a single call to insert take 100 seconds, or does building the entire tree take 100 seconds?

Comment: @drBet: the problem is probably located somewhere else since [this ideone](http://ideone.com/VZCXlm) only requires ~40 milliseconds to process 100k inserts (yeah I know its only a test, but there is a huge difference between 100s and 40ms). The only problem I can think of is that the data is sorted and you thus create a linked list. This tree is not self balancing, thus if the data is ordered, this will result in problems.

Comment: Or you are doing some queries in between, like for instance asking the tree height which is - if not stored - an expensive operation.

Comment: @Dathan no building the whole tree takes 100 seconds

Comment: @CommuSoft yes I know, I mean logically it shouldn't take that much, but I have gone thorugh the code again, and again the whole day today, and I just can't figure out the problem

Comment: @CommuSoft nope I am not doing that either (I believe because I don't do the test, it's another class taht I have to rung, but it says for example: ...\instances\0002: DBG Insertion test took 96.847199234 seconds)

Comment: @drBet: can you provide (a link to) the file. Because as said before a non-balancing tree works poorly on some sequences of data.

Comment: @CommuSoft Ohhh thank you so much for the help!!! My eyes are twitching already from the lack of sleep! http://pastebin.com/zKJws4Yk

Comment: @CommuSoft and the test file has these numbers http://pastebin.com/XHqzwewy

Answer (score 1):

if you use the function defined in line 270 for insertion, the long time is actually explainable.

look at this piece of code :

```
public void insert(int val) {

        if (root == null) {
            nodes++;
            root = new Node(val);
        } else if (!root.exists(val)) {
            root.insert(val);
        }

    }
```

this calls a function exists(), which is defined as follows:

```
boolean exists(int val) {
            return val == this.elem
                    || (val < this.elem ? (this.left != null && this.left.exists(val))
                            : (this.right != null && this.right.exists(val)));
        }
```

and as you see this piece of code, you can easily figure out that maybe each time you call this function, your code traverses the whole tree recursively! so if you do insertion 100K times, your code runs in O(n^2*logn) time at worst, so 100 seconds is actually a good running time!

I think what you have to do is modify your exists() function.